# CodeIgniter inserting auto increment

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm doing a basic add user form for work and I'm trying to add a user to the database however when I try I just get the primary key is being duplicated error. Pretty sure the solution is looking me right in the face but I've hit a wall today lol.

database table struture

dbo.ci_users

```
id(PK, int, not null)
user_name(nchar255, not null)
user_email(nchar255, not null)
user_password(nchar255, not null)
user_displayname(nchar255, not null)
user_active(smallint, not null)
user_level(smallint, not null)
```

Adduser_model

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class adduser_database extends CI_Model {

         function __construct()
        {
            // Call the Model constructor
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
        }

    public function insert_into_db()
    {
        $data = array(
            'id'            => '0',
            'user_active'        => '1',
            'user_level'         => '2',
            'user_displayname'   => $this->input->post('user_displayname'),
            'user_email'         => $this->input->post('user_email'),
            'user_name'      => $this->input->post('user_name'),
            'user_password'      => $this->input->post('user_password') 
        );

        $this->db->insert('ci_users', $data);

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried it but I am now getting this error Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'ClientPortal.dbo.ci_users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: if id is auto_increment remove     'id'            => '0', from array and try

Comment: @Piglet add this ALTER TABLE `ci_users`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

Comment: Will affect any of the values that are already int his database? as we have 20 users already in there just wondering if this change will delete them?

Comment: @Piglet No. It will not affect your previous records.

Comment: Im getting this now Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'MODIFY'.

Comment: @Piglet try like this ALTER TABLE `ci_users` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

Comment: @Piglet i edited my answer. Now you check it.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the same idea out of this but not by changing the database properties for instance could I use a select max query then increase it by 1 for ID I understand this is no doubt bad practise but for the meanwhile it could work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are specifying a primary key value which is the same for all of your inserts. That is why you are getting that error. Remove that line of code and let MySQL specify that value for you as AUTO_INCREMENT means MySQL will assign the next value automatically with every insert:

```
$data = array(
    'id'          => '0', // <-- REMOVE THIS
    'user_active' => '1',
```

**edit**

Looks like you forgot to add AUTO_INCREMENT to your table. This code fix that:

```
ALTER TABLE ci_users CHANGE id id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, upon removing this I got this error, Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'ClientPortal.dbo.ci_users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: @Piglet I have updated my answer to show you how to add the auto increment to your table

Comment: What I mean is this is what I get Im getting this now Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'CHANGE'.

Answer (score 0):

```
First of all you have to change in database and make AUTO_INCREMENT id then use the following code. It will helps you 

public function insert_into_db()
{
    $data = array(

        'user_active'        => '1',
        'user_level'         => '2',
        'user_displayname'   => $this->input->post('user_displayname'),
        'user_email'         => $this->input->post('user_email'),
        'user_name'      => $this->input->post('user_name'),
        'user_password'      => $this->input->post('user_password') 
    );

    $this->db->insert('ci_users', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a model definition from your table, be sure to change the boolean parameter:

```
protected $useAutoIncrement = true;
```